# FMX Listview Search Virtual Keyboard Switch to Numbers

Tags: android, listview, delphi, firemonkey

I have a ListView , and when I click on the Search bar the Default Keyboard Shows up , this is fine. The only thing I wish to change is that it should show Numbers per Default instead of ABC .

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

Meanwhile I was trying myself to go further ... and found this :

```
procedure TOutput.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var SearchBox : TSearchBox;
    i : integer;

begin
  for I := 0 to lvInventory.Controls.Count-1 do
    if lvInventory.Controls[I].ClassType = TSearchBox then
    begin
      SearchBox := TSearchBox(lvInventory.Controls[I]);
      Break;
    end;

  SearchBox.KeyboardType:=TVirtualKeyboardType.NumberPad;
end;
```

This does work , but it would be preferred to have the Alphabet show up but with Numbers as default view.
If that is not an option , then I will in worst case but a Button on the form to allow the user to switch the TSearchBox between modes.

Comment: TVirtualKeyboardType has lots of keyboards to choose from. Cant find one you like?

Comment: @DougRudd the Question was : to have the "Default" one but it being switched to Number and Signs . So that the user still has the option to switch back . If I do it like above , the user cannot change the keyboard. But to tell you the truth I am not even sure if this is doable on Android.